# ngrx/store 4: get unexpected sub state when selecting from store

Tags: angular, ngrx-store-4.0

I have several sub stores. Lets say `Sub1` and `Sub2` with the following states and reducers (actions are not interesting for my problem ... I guess):

**Sub1:**

```
export interface Sub1State {
  sub1value: string
}

export function sub1reducer(state: Sub1State, action: Action): Sub1State {
  ...
}
```

**Sub2:**

```
export interface Sub2State {
  sub2value: number
}

export function sub2reducer(state: Sub2State, action: Action): Sub2State {

}
```

Then I combine these two sub states into one `ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState>`:

```
export interface ApplicationState {
  sub1: Sub1State,
  sub2: Sub2State
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
  sub1: sub1reducer,
  sub2: sub2reducer
};
```

And 'register' it to the Store:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
```

Now, in a Angular component, I want to select the `Sub1` store and get the `sub1value` string. So I do ...

```
sub1value$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private store: Store<Sub1State>) {
  this.sub1value$ = store.map(state => {
    console.log(state);
    return state.sub1value;
  });
}
```

In the log statement, I would expect to get the following object (the Sub1State object):

```
{
  sub1value: 'initial value'
}
```

But what I really get is this object:

```
{
  sub1: {
    sub1value: 'initial value'
  }
}
```

Is this working as intended? If yes, how shall I work with the interface Sub1State? Because `sub1`is not part of the interface.

And also curious is, I don't get any error (neither compiler error nor runtime error) when calling `state.sub1value` what is obviously wrong because it must be `state.sub1.sub1value`. No runtime error I understand, it is simply undefined. But the TypeScript compiler should throw an error here in my opinion.

I am really confused :/

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how I would expect it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w34kua?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the application's state, it is returning an object. Your state has two substates in it, they are called sub1 and sub2. Each of those is its own object. So it is working as expected. You would need to do 'return state.sub1.sub1value;

Or what I usually do, is I subscribe to a specific reducer by doing something like this, then I only get that specific substate back and not the whole state:

```
constructor(private store: Store<Sub1State>) {
  store.select('sub1').subscribe((state : Sub1State) => {
    console.log(state);
    this.sub1value$ = state.sub1value;
  });
}
```

Comment: But how then selector functions work correctly? I saw in most examples a signature like `getValue1(state: Sub1State): string`. But if i pass this selector function to `store.select(getValue1)` it will not work because the object passed to the selector function is not of type `Sub1State` but with the `sub1` root element. Also a store with the sub state is injected `constructor(private store: Store<Sub1State>)`.

Comment: If you do what I described you will get the sub1 state back. Do store.select('sub1').subscribe(.......). That will give you the sub1 state object

Comment: Okay, right, that works. But if I do it this way, I could also just write a simple service where I have to subscribe and unsubscribe manually. I lose some of the cool features of the Flux/Redux/Store architecture. But I don't want to subscribe and unsubscribe by hand, I just want to have a slice of the application state and save it in a local observable. Here is an example what I would expect to work, but does not work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w34kua?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts